# Magento Call a function of Model in Controller

Tags: model, controllers, mvc

I have a function `abc` in a model. I want to call that function `abc` in the controller.

I am new to Magento and don't have any idea regarding this.
Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called Magic Function.

```
$yourModel = Mage::getModel('yourmodulename/yourmodelname')->load($id);

$return = $yourModel->abc();
```

or you can do

```
$yourModel = Mage::getSingleton('yourmodulename/yourmodelname')->load($id);

$return = $yourModel->abc();
```

this is for your reference of [getSingleton VS getModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756753/magento-getsingleton-vs-getmodel-issue)

Comment: magic functions are a complete other area in PHP.  
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename')->yourMethod();
```

Suppose you want catalog category  then

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your configuration is -

```
    <models>
        <modulename> <!--  this here is the first part of your getModel() call -->
            <class>Packagename_Modulename_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </modulename>
        <modulename_mysql4>
            <class>Packagename_Modulename_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <abc>
                    <table>table_abc</table>
                </abc>
            </entities>
        </modulename_mysql4>
    </models>
```

Now you need the second part after the `/`. If your model name is: `Packagename_Modulename_Model_Abc`, then you take everything after your prefix, which was defined in the config `Packagename_Modulename_Model`, **lowercase the first** character

Now you can access your model following way:

```
Mage::getModel('modulename/abc')->yourMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the model lives in a subfolder of your module, you need to load it like:

`Mage::getModel('yourmodelname_as_defined_in_config/path_to_file_filename')`

**Example**

**Load** `app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Log.php`

**like** `Mage::getModel('smtppro/email_log');`